# terminate persisted Workflow after specific time

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

i use windows Workflow fundation for handle many step of wizard, and after per step completed, workflow persisted and control back to user for new step, in some case may be user not completed all steps of wizard, in this case i want terminated uncompleted wizard, for this i want use a timeout time, but i do not know how do this with workflow.

another problem is i want set userId or username of current user per instance of workflow but i do not know how do this, plz guide me, tnx;

Answer (score 0):

You Cancel or Terminate workflows from outside of the workflow.  You do the work at the level where you created the WorkflowApplication.

Assuming you start your workflow as an application like this:

```
WorkflowApplication _wfApp = new WorkflowApplication(new YourWorkFlow(), inParams);
_wfApp.Run();
```

Then you have a reference to the WorkflowApplication as wfApp.

So you can set up a timer and then use the reference when the timer fires to terminate the workflow.

```
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

wfApp.Terminate(new ApplicationException("Terminating the workflow."));
```

You can detect the termination by capturing the workflow completed event.

```
wfApp.Completed = delegate(WorkflowApplicationCompletedEventArgs e)
{  Do your clean up code here }
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd781832(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

As regards your second question, are you asking how you pass the userId or username of the current user into a workflow when it starts?

If so then you create a dictionary holding the parameters you want to use and you pass it into the WorkflowApplication object before you run the workflow.

```
IDictionary<string, object> inParams = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"UserID", "12345678" },
                {"UserName", "Bob" }
            };
WorkflowApplication _wfApp = new WorkflowApplication(new YourWorkFlow(), inParams);
_wfApp.Run();
```

You must set up your workflow so that it has In Arguments called UserID and UserName of type string.  You don't need to always use string. You can pass in any Type you want.

Comment: in my application may be user begin flow and after persist flow usernot complete flow and this is garbage in database, if may be after a time(timeout time) remove persisted flow row in database

Comment: Your first comment is too ambiguous to answer.  For your second comment: When you Terminate a workflow the persistence record is removed automatically from the persistence database

Comment: tnx for answer, but i want after same time automatically remove workflow persist records that yet not completeی, i dont know workflow has this feasibility

Comment: When you issue the command wfApp.Terminate, the persisted records are removed from the persistence database. The workflow does not need to be complete.  Issuing the wfApp.Terminate automatically completes the workflow. This is in the first answer I gave above.